# How to reuse a self-invoking function

Tags: jquery

I am using a selfinvoking function to display images in an image-gallery. After clicking on the back- and forth-buttons the same function is used again.

Is there a way to store and reuse the same function without writing the entire function again and again?

Heres my selfinwoking function:

```
(function run_kunst_slide() {   
$('.slideren.kunst_slider').fadeIn(300);

$('.slide_this_kunst').hide();
$('.slide_this_kunst:first-child').show().appendTo('.slideren.kunst_slider');

$('.slide_this_kunst').eq(-2).addClass( 'get_prev_slide' );
$('.slide_this_kunst:first-child').after().addClass( 'get_next_slide' ); 

$('img.kunsteksempel').hide().fadeIn(300);
$('.slider_kategori:nth-child(2)').addClass( 'active_kategori' );

setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.slide_this_kunst').eq(-2).removeClass( 'get_prev_slide' );
    $('.slide_this_kunst:first-child').after().removeClass( 'get_next_slide' );
}, 1900);

setTimeout(run_kunst_slide, 2000);

})();
```

Comment: Removing the ( and )() would make it reusable

Comment: Make it a normal function that you invoke normally.

Comment: Im not good at Jquery - can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but I would say there is a way of reusing self-invoke function.

Name of that function is invoked inside and accessible only from inside.

To access from outside we need to add to the global context.

```js
var counter = 0;

(function autoExec(){
  console.log(`number: ${counter}`);
  //adding to global context
  window.autoExec = autoExec;
  counter++;
})();


autoExec();
autoExec();
autoExec();
autoExec();
```